# How to copy a required chunk of data from a text file to device node (file opened using open) for dma

Tags: c, file, gcc, file-io

I have this file called **input.txt** opened using **file pointer**. Now I want to read this file and write this data into device node file using **write()** system call(Any better way). Right now I am scanning integer values one by one and writing to device node. Any way so that I can do this in block say some fixed number of bytes. **input.txt** contain 32 bit integers seperated by newline. Below is the code I have right now.

```
FILE *fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
int fd = open("/dev/devnode", O_WRONLY);
int current = 0; 
while(!feof(fp))
   {
       fscanf(fp,"%x\n", &current)
       write(fd,&current,sizeof(int));
       trigger_dma_to_device();
   }
```

Is there any better way to do this? Please help.

**EDIT:** 
To put my requirement clearly I write to device node and then have to trigger DMA but DMA capacity is 1024 bytes so rather than writing one integer (**32** bytes) I want to read **32** integers (**1024** bytes) from **input.txt** and write it to device node before triggering **dma**. Any way this can be done without allocating extra memory. I'm OK with loop to start with.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong

Comment: @Mat My doubt is not about usage of feof. I want to know how I can copy data from one file to another say a chunk of 128 bytes or some x number of integers.

Comment: What you have there does not copy a file. It reads a text files, and outputs binary data. If you want to copy, just use read/write, not fscanf. And you should really have doubts about feof, you're not using it properly.

Comment: @Mat Thanks for the reply. I have not run into any issues with my usage of feof but I will check as you pointed. I have edited the question to give more info, let me know if you can help. Please ask more question if you need to. TIA

Comment: Basically I have to read the input file and not just copy, because the data needs to be parsed. Can I do something where I can read and parse my input while appending to device node till U reach dma limit before triggering DMA. Not sure if I clear so please ask.